# Why I cannot compare factored vector with the whole dataframe?

Tags: r

When i try to compare a simple(non-factor) vector with a whole data frame, it turns out fine. However whenever i try to compare a factored vector with a data frame it raise an error.

Consider this code,

```
df <- data.frame(
  name = c('Abdul', 'Wahhab', 'Zahid', 'Hussain', 'Rana')
)
names <- c('Abdul', 'Wahhab', 'Zahid', 'Hussain', 'Rana')
```

Now, when these are compared,

```
names == df
```

Results :

```
[1,] TRUE
[2,] TRUE
[3,] TRUE
[4,] TRUE
[5,] TRUE
```

Now after factoring the 'names' vector the comparison gives an error;

```
factored_names <- factor(names)
factored_names == df
```

ERROR:-

```
Warning: Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "Ops.data.frame") for "=="
Error in factored_names == df (to_ask.R#10): comparison of these types is not implemented
```

I understand that after factoring, the vector's values are no longer characters but are now in an integer form. Basically each value/level/category is now representing a integer value and after labeling the factored vector's values we can say the vice versa. Since the values are in integer form or representing integers, it makes sense that characters/String cannot be compared with the integers.

However, coming to the main point, when i specify a column ,to whom i wanna compare, whether it is factored attribute or non-factored even if it is an non-integer type of attribute, it compares it happily.

```
factored_names == df$name
```

Results:

```
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

So why it is not comparing the whole data frame but comparing a single attribute at a time even if it is an integer or non-integer, factored or not factored?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `a == b` this is equivalent to  `` `==`(a, b) ``. The method that is dispatched is (initially) based on the class of `a`.

So, if you looked at the code for the `==` method for `character` vectors, there something there to handle what happens when `b` is a data frame. My guess is that a data frame `b` is converted to a `matrix`, and then the comparison is done that way, but I haven't looked to verify that.

Apparently, as the error message tells us, there is no such method to handle the case when `a` is a `factor` and `b` is a `data.frame`.

When you specify a column, then it is class of the specific column on the RHS of `==`, and there are implementations of `==` for `factor` with another `factor`, a `character` or a `numeric`.

Since there are easy workarounds like `as.character(factored_names) == df` or `factored_names == as.matrix(df)` or `sapply(df, "==", factored_names)`, and this is a pretty uncommon use case, I doubt there are any plans to implement a `==` method with factors on the LHS and data frames on the RHS.